# How to integrate a html bootstrap code into a javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I wrote a html website. There is a button created with bootstrap. I want to change the design of the button and the label text on it, depending on a boolean variable.

Here are the two types of buttons:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    <center><strong>Open</strong></center>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <center><strong>Close</strong></center>
</div>
```

How can I integrate this html buttons in this javascript code?:

```
    <script>
    var open = true;

    if (open = true) {


    } else {

    }

</script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: just as a remark, it should be `if(open === true) {}` or `if(open) {}` a single equals is invalid in that context

Comment: yes, I am. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use predefined bootstrap class `hidden` (also there is deprecated class `hide`):

```
var open = false;

if (open) {
   $(".alert-success").addClass("hidden");
   $(".alert-danger").removeClass("hidden");
} else {
   $(".alert-success").removeClass("hidden");
   $(".alert-danger").addClass("hidden");
};
```

Or you can define one button only:

```js
var open = true;

    if (open) {
     $(".alert").addClass("alert-success");
     $(".alert").removeClass("alert-danger");
     $(".alert").html("<center><strong>Open</strong></center>");
   } else {
     $(".alert").removeClass("alert-success");
     $(".alert").addClass("alert-danger");
     $(".alert").html("<center><strong>Close</strong></center>");
    };
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert" role="alert"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! You are brilliant, this helped me a lot! I'm glad I signed up to this page! :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is an great example of how you can make the div disappear with button click using pure javascript

```
    var button = document.getElementById('button');

    button.onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementByClass('alert alert-success');
    if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
    div.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/hefGK/

So you can simply change the design as you wish by changing the style.display to style.color and match the code aswell.

Comment: thanks, but It should change without pressing a button

Comment: So I would highly recommend jQuery, it will be a lot more simple.